# Applications Folder on Macintosh HD Shows Empty

Tags: applications, time-machine, migration

Before attempting to migrate data from my Time Machine, I looked in to see if my Adobe applications and others were there to transfer.  The folder is empty.  Is this normal?  Thanks.

Comment: Is this the `/Applications` folder in your _user account_, or the  `Macintosh HD/Applications folder`?

Comment: Also, is this the empty folder in the Macintosh HD volume, or on the TM backup volume?

Answer (score 1):

There are two `Application` folders. One is under the root directory and should contain all of your Applications. This is `/Applications`

The other folder is in the User directory, so `~/Applications`. `~/` is a shorthand for `/Users/<UserName>`. That folder is usually empty or has one or two stray Apps in there.